# How do I get all repeated ids while leaving the higher alone in firebird 2

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-2.0

I have the following table, I want to get all ids that have a plate that repeats, while leaving the ids that have unique plates alone and keeping the higher ids in plates that repeats.

```
id   plate
1    1000
2    2000
3    5000
4    5000
5    1000
6    1000
7    5000
```

Perform a select to get ids 3 and 1. Id 2 is not included because it is unique and 4 and 5 are higher in their repeated plates.  I've tried a lot, but the limitations of Firebird 2.0 just keep me from achieving the results.

Comment: I want to the opposite of it. I want the repeated plates ids that are now the max(id). If  repeated i want the max if doesn't repeated leave it alone.

Comment: What are the expected results 1,3 or 4,5?

Comment: so then min(ID) is what you're after grouping by plate having a count(*) > 1.  The count(*) >1 eliminates the unique plates.

Comment: Given the updated data set, what are the expected results? 1,3,4,5?  I'm unable to determine the pattern/rule you want.

Comment: Firebird 2.0 has been end-of-life since April 2012. Please consider upgrading.

Comment: I want now 1 5, 3, 4.

Answer (score 1):

In both of the below we exclude ID 2 because the plate only occurs once.

Returns the MAX ID of any plate having more than 1 ID. So this would be 4 and 5

```
SELECT max(ID) as maxID, plate 
FROM table 
GROUP BY plate 
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Returns the Min ID of any plate having more than 1 ID. So this would be 1 and 3.

```
SELECT min(ID) as MinID, plate 
FROM table 
GROUP BY plate 
HAVING count(*) > 1
```